# Magento2 Create extra column in eav_attribute and eav_attribute_option table

Tags: magento2, eav, eav-attributes

I have created one extra column in the `eav_attribute` and `eav_attribute_option` table. Now I want to store values in those tables when I will create **new attributes**.

Please suggest options.

Comment: Why You need an extra column on this table?

Comment: I want to save ID's(from ERP system) in the eav_attribute table for that attributes and option_id's(also from ERP system) in the eav_attribute_option table